# Button aligned bottom on equal height columns

Tags: jquery, css, alignment, multiple-columns

I'm using an equal height column layout and now I need to place a button that must be always aligned at the bottom of each column.

Any ideas?

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/JucVm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i changed this style class:

you can remove the background, i'v added it just for testing!

```
 .content {
        margin-bottom:30px;
        position: relative;
        background: #bb0000;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

and added this class:

```
.content div.btn-align-bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VTV6B/

**UPDATE:** i removed your Javascript and replaced it with something simpler, take a look at the css too, here is the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VTV6B/2/

Comment: Thanks. I'm testing your solution at the moment

Comment: Mmm... it didn't quite work. The buttons vanished. Here's the website I'm building. http://creativmouse.com/naptg/events.html It might be better to see the real thing in action ;)

Comment: @user1628193, glad that i could help!

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
.col {position: relative; padding-bottom: 60px;}
.btn-align-bottom {position: absolute; bottom: 30px;}
```

Comment: Your solution works however I need to have a 30px margin between the text and the button and the button a margin bottom of 30px

Comment: No probs. I've updated the code to account for that. Putting bottom padding on the `.col` div and positioning the button within that padding means there can't be text overlap.

Comment: Thanks Ralph but it didn't work :( Do u think it would be better if I show u the actual page I'm building?

Comment: Certainly, the real example is always better. It worked in the fiddle for me.